# How can I execute a source (dot) command via SSH?

Tags: sh, ksh

I have a `do_something.sh` on a ksh device I will run from a sh PC via SSH. Before I run this script, I need to execute another `setup.inc` file using the abbreviated source command. Is there a way to do this using SSH?

So far, I've tried a number of variations (i.e., tweaking single and double quotes) on the following:

```
ssh root@$device_ip ". $path_to_folder/bin/setup.inc"
ssh root@$device_ip "$path_to_folder/bin/do_something.sh"
```

I've also tried:

```
ssh root@$device_ip ". $path_to_folder/bin/setup.inc; $path_to_folder/bin/do_something.sh"
```

However, `do_something.sh` has yet to work correctly, and I know it is because the execution of `setup.inc` hasn't worked yet. I'm boggled as to what's going wrong. Is there something about SSH getting in the way? Is it that the device uses ksh? Is what I'm trying to do actually possible at all?

Comment: Did you try "./$path_to_folder/bin/setup.inc"

Comment: Running two `ssh` commands runs in two separate subshells on the remote host. (so your source is lost after the first command completes) If you are trying to source into the current execution environment of the `ssh` command on the remote host and then call `do_something.sh` in that same environment, then use a compound command, e.g. `ssh root@$device_ip ". $path_to_folder/bin/setup.inc && $path_to_folder/bin/do_something.sh"` and `path_to_folder` must be set in the environment on the remote host.

Comment: Your third attempt `"...; ..."` should work as intended. If not, there may be a problem with `setup.inc` itself. Have you tried logging into the remote host and running the commands manually?

Comment: @chepner, you're right. The `ssh root@$device_ip ". $path_to_folder/bin/setup.inc; $path_to_folder/bin/do_something.sh"` option works. With all the different variations of things I'd been trying, I must not have entered it exactly right or something. Coming back the next day helped me fix the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got it figured out. It turns out that @chepner was correct; this works:

```
ssh root@$device_ip ". $path_to_folder/bin/setup.inc; $path_to_folder/bin/do_something.sh"
```